# how to find the date range in uri request search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search in which i need to find the delta of data 
http://localhost:9200/index/index_type/_search?q=sampledate[21-02-2015 TO 22-02-2015]

but this search is giving me error
could anybody help?

Comment: please post more details and code your localhost wont work here..

Comment: Show the mapping of your index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below query:

```
GET /index_name/index_type/_search?q=dateCreated:[2016-01-06+TO+2016-01-07]
```

**This will work only if `dateCreated` is a `date` field. Won't work with `String`**

Comment: Hi it is giving me ambigous results, I just verified sometimes its giving me the data of the date which is not even mentioned in the query. The query I used http://localhost:9200/index/csv/_search?pretty&q=sampleTime:[01/2/2016+TO+10/2/2016]&fields=alias,Instance,Type,sampleTime

Comment: What is the datatype of sampleTime? Is it date or String?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar weird issue with this date field in Elastic Search 7.6.1.

We found working solution by removing colon(:) after date fields and surrounding entire date query part with brackets.

i.e.
GET /index_name/index_type/_search?q=dateCreated:[2016-01-06+TO+2016-01-07]

Above query changed to

GET /index_name/index_type/_search?q=(dateCreated[2016-01-06+TO+2016-01-07]) This should work