# Searching elasticsearch from R using URI string with @timestamp range

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am trying to modify working URI search from R to retrieve data from ElasticSearch using time  range on @timestamp es variable:

here is the uri string:

```
myuri01 <- paste0(  'myserver01:9201/filebeat-*/_search?pretty=true&size=9000&sort:@timestamp&q=%2BSESTYPE:APPTYPE001%20 2Bhost:mytesthost%20%2B@timestamp>"2016-10-25T18:59:23.250Z"') 

retset = getURL(myuri01 )
```

but I get no data, no errors ...  Also tried without double quote around time stamp - same result.  If I remove the last timestamp part then I do get the data as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: .. also tried uri above that ends with %20%2B@timestamp>2016-10-24') - then the timestamp range gets completely ignored and returning data set has the same data as if @timestamp was not there at all ...

Comment: it's probably a problem with url encoding. Did you try the `elastic` package yet? it may not solve your problem, but if it doesn't, i can help

Comment: Thanks Scott - will try it - just downloaded it - will take a detailed look tomorrow - seems more like admin R interface but I see quite a few search functions - will check it out ...

Comment: Found it - it was the format of the time range URI component - this link provides the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265465/how-to-find-the-date-range-in-uri-request-search-in-elasticsearch

Comment: .. last part of the uri that works now is this: @timestamp:[2016-10-20+TO+2016-10-27]')

Comment: Your other deleted question would have been answered with: `format( Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS3Z")` . Read: `?format.POSIXct` . I also cleaned up the formatting on this one. You should do more study in the help pages for SO.